# exit from powershell script causes Unhandled exception

Tags: powershell, exit-code, exit

I am trying to execute `exit` after closing the form when clicking "NO" button, but `exit` causes a system error

Code:

```
    function No {
            $Form.close()
            exit
    }
$NoButton.Add_Click({No})
```

Without exit, it closes the form but it continues executing the script

System error:

> Unhandled exception has occured in a component in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and
>   attempt to continue.
>
> System error.

Full button code:

```
function No {
    $Form.close()
    exit
                    } #end No
# No button
$NoButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$NoButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95,80) 
$NoButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20) 
$NoButton.Text = "No" 
$NoButton.Add_Click({No}) 
$NoButton.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Form.Controls.Add($NoButton)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error when using `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($Form)` to display the window - could you please show code necessary to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till the `$Form` is actually closed and then better kill it's own process:

```
$NoButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$NoButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95,80) 
$NoButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20) 
$NoButton.Text = "No" 
$NoButton.Add_Click({$Form.close()}) 
$NoButton.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Form.Controls.Add($NoButton)
$Form.Add_Closed({Stop-Process -ID $PID})    # Kill it's own process when the form is closed
```

Comment: This offers a workaround but doesn't explain why using `exit` causes the error.