# PowerShell "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Tags: powershell, bitmap

Hi Guys, I'm trying to modify this *PowerShell script* and put it in windows startup. So every restart a VBScript will call this PowerShell script and it will update the info like a Windows Sysinternals BGinfo.
https://pastebin.com/nDh2L9dm

```
# Close Graphics
$image.Dispose();

# Save and close Bitmap
$background.Save($out, [system.drawing.imaging.imageformat]::Png);
$background.Dispose();
$bmp.Dispose();

# Output file
Get-Item -Path $out
```

This is the error I get in **PowerShell ISE**

> Exception calling "Save" with "2" argument(s): "A generic error occurred in GDI+."
>   At D:\Desktop\PS-BGInfo-My-Version.ps1:195 char:5
>   +     $background.Save($out, [system.drawing.imaging.imageformat]::Png) ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExternalException

Comment: Check if your `$out` is something and not null. Also saving function might require additional parameters or require to display a "save as" window, which is impossible if you don't have a graphics context (aka ran as batch job). Also, not enough data.

Comment: Did you load `$background` or `$bmp` from `$out` in the first place?

Comment: You not showing the whole script but I guess that you are either disposing objects to early or exiting (using `Exit`) the host (PowerShell) while the GDI is still busy (saving). Close the GDI form first using the `Close()` method and when you sure it is closed, exit the PowerShell script (`$Form.Add_Closed({Stop-Process -ID $PID})`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46811244/1701026